# Using google-guice with out bind code

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

Is the any way to bind classes not via code:

```
 bind(MessageService.class).to(FacebookService.class);
 Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new AppInjector());
```

But with some annotation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to use annotations to specify bindings, it is explained in the [Guice docs](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/JustInTimeBindings). An example from that page:

```
@ImplementedBy(PayPalCreditCardProcessor.class)
public interface CreditCardProcessor {
  ChargeResult charge(String amount, CreditCard creditCard)
      throws UnreachableException;
}

@ProvidedBy(DatabaseTransactionLogProvider.class)
public interface TransactionLog {
  void logConnectException(UnreachableException e);
  void logChargeResult(ChargeResult result);
}
```

`@ImplementedBy` and `@ProvidedBy` annotations allow to specify bindings implicitly.

However, I'd argue that this is not really a good way to define bindings. Explicitly defined bindings are more composable, and they are concentrated in modules hence they are easier to manage.